# How to grant permission on all views in a schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following statement correctly grants the select permission on all **tables** in the specified Schema: '', but none of the **views** within that Schema.  Why?

```
USE Dealing
GO

GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA :: <Schema> TO <Role>
```

Must I really specify each of the Views I require? :

```
GRANT SELECT ON <Schema>.<View1> TO <Role>
GRANT SELECT ON <Schema>.<View2> TO <Role>
GRANT SELECT ON <Schema>.<View3> TO <Role>
```

Is there no similar mechanism to grant permissions on all views within a Schema ?

Comment: Hmm... it works for me while doing a simple test (that is a schema-level `SELECT` grant gives select permissions on the view as well). Do you have any `DENY` permissions present anywhere in your database (check `sys.database_permissions`). Are these views simple (i.e. don't access any objects outside of your database)?